# How to enable Dungeon Siege 3 Demo Co-op?

Tags: steam, dungeon-siege-3

There's been much fuss raised about the local co-op in this demo, with the caveat that you need to have two controllers attached. Both controllers are recognized and lit up, but I can't seem to find an option anywhere to get the second player to appear, or to start a two player game.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just have to reach a certain point. Eventually the 2nd controller was able to join in with the start button - but it didn't work right off the bat.